# python ttk checked checkbutton

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

i'm trying to start a program with the checkbutton selected but I don't know how to do it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
v = tk.IntVar()
cb = ttk.Checkbutton(root,text='Remember user',onvalue=1,offvalue=0, variable = v);cb.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `select()` method:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
cb = Checkbutton(root,text='Remember user',onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
cb.pack()
cb.select()
```

Answer (score 1):

One can simply instantiate the variable with a desired value, such as `1`:

```
v = tk.IntVar(value=1)
```

which is the same `onvalue` represented by `cb`. Since its value and `v` is the very same, and since `v` is the attached `variable`, it will be selected from the very beginning.